Debug Problem of STM32 with Keil
As a beginner I want to learn freeRTOS. Accordingly, I need to have access to the debug section in the KEIL. I test debug with two STM32 Dev Boards including bluepill(stm32f103) and blackpill (stm32f401) but in both of them when I press run it stuck in one line it does not run to the next steps. However, I have worked with debug in another programs with different microcontrollers like stm32f030 without problem.

